# Iniciando o Tomcat 7 (java 7)

Tags: java, tomcat

Estou instalando o Jdk7 e o tomcat 7.
A instalação do jdk7 foi normal sem nenhum problema e as variáveis de sistemas também já foram criadas e direcionadas.
Depois de feito essa etapa eu fui instalar o tomcat 7, porém no início estava dando um erro de instalação pois já havia um tomcat service na minha máquina.
O que eu fiz foi ir até aonde estava instalado o outro tomcat (obs: não é a mesma versão), e removi o servidor.bat; só retirei da pasta para ser mais exato, depois tentei instalar novamente o tomcat 7 e a instalação foi concluída normalmente. Fiz as configurações necessárias de direcionamento para o jre.
Entretanto quando fui tentar iniciar o tomcat pela tela de serviços ocorreu o erro abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fui ver o s logs de erros e foram esses que me apareceram

```
Running 'Tomcat7' Service...
Starting service...
CreateJavaVM Failed
O sistema não pôde encontrar a opção de ambiente digitada.
Failed to start Java ServiceStart returned 4
Run service finished.
Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

Comment: você instalou o jdk e o jre do java ?

Comment: Vá até a instação (unzip) do Tomcat, entre na pasta `bin` e execute a bat `shutdown.bat` e tente novamente.

Comment: Você "instalou" o Tomcat? Você precisa apenas baixar o zip, extrair e rodar o script de start.

Comment: Talvez você esteja tentando inicializar o tomcat que já estava instanlado e como removeu o arquivo ele não funciona. Rode o tomcat 7 pelo CMD do windows, por exemplo: `C:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7\bin>catalina start`

Answer (score 0):

Desculpa pessoal, fui ver depois que o erro estava no Java Options da configuração do Tomcat 7
eu demorei pra perceber e com a ajuda de um colega eu percebi.
Ah também, vi que tinha um serviço do tomcat instalado também, ai eu tinha que remove-lo também.
Ou seja, no fim eu removi o serviço de um tomcat antigo, e configurei corretamente o Java Options do Tomcat.
Mesmo assim eu agradeço a todos da comunidade que se dispuseram a responder foram dicas validas e peço desculpas pela demora

Comment: como eu encerro a questão?